# viola jones algorithm clarification

Tags: image-processing, viola-jones

As mentioned in the [paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eefros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf), while training the classifier `24x24` images are used.

But for face detection on image of size `1024x1600` which contains face of size `500x500` how is the face detected if we are using `24x24` windows to detect face?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm disassembles the image into 24-by-24 sub-images and in each sub-image, he tries to find a face. Due to this fact, the viola jones algorithm can find more than one face in the image.

I find a really good summary of the viola jones algorithm process [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sxfp5k249eoxB57cbcS9vl4zi3gBe0la/view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE3R6.png)

[suumery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLxo4.png)

you can read more about that [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=Aarrm0eBe58C&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=haar%20cascades%20subwindow&source=bl&ots=EgvzhTnzOB&sig=ACfU3U3oNaeYLc6mrC8BSbFuxt7DrHlp6Q&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX7ZnYpN70AhXgAGMBHVO6CCcQ6AF6BAguEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false)
[Image Analysis: 15th Scandinavian Conference, SCIA 2007, Aalborg, Denmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Sh0.png)